# ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found while inserting into Oracle Database with X threads

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, executorservice, ora-12519

I am trying to insert into Oracle database which has two columns-

```
ID         Primary Key     varchar2 (4000)
ACCOUNT                    varchar2 (4000)
```

I wrote a Multithreaded program for that. And each thread is using `unique id` every time to insert into `ID column` as `ID` is primary key.

The only problem that I am facing at some point is- The below code, throws following exception after running for few seconds.

```
 1) Null Pointer Exception
 2) java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
```

I am not able to find any root cause of this problem in my code as everything is looking good to me. As I am closing each and every connection properly. Then how does this NPE is getting thrown and other exception as well?

```
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    try {
        // queue some tasks
        for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 10; i++) {
            service.submit(new ThreadTask());
        }
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        while (!service.isTerminated()) {

        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOG.warn("Threw a Interrupted Exception in" + XMPLoadTest.class.getSimpleName()
                + ".XMPLoadTest: boss told me to stop...Not my fault!!");
    }
```

Below is ThreadTask class-

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {

    private static final String DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL";
    private static final String USER = "scott";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "tiger";
    private static Connection dbConnection = null;
    private static PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    private static final AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger(1);

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ThreadTask.class.getName());

    public ThreadTask() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(Constants.INSERT_ORACLE_SQL);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, String.valueOf(id.getAndIncrement()));
            preparedStatement.setString(2, Constants.A_ACCOUNT);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // NPE getting thrown here/And second exception as well
            LOG.error("Threw a SQLException in " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
        } finally {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                try {
                    preparedStatement.close();
                    preparedStatement = null;
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    //Oouch...
                    LOG.error("Threw a SQLException in finally block of prepared statement " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
                }
            }
            if (dbConnection != null) {
                try {
                    dbConnection.close();
                    dbConnection = null;
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    //Better go and look for SQL.
                    LOG.error("Threw a SQLException in finally block of dbConnection " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to establish a connection to the given database URL
     * 
     * @return the db connection
     */
    private Connection getDBConnection() {

        Connection dbConnection = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(XMP_DRIVER);
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION, USER, PASSWORD);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LOG.error("Threw a ClassNotFoundException in " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //DAMN! I'm not....
            LOG.error("Threw a SQLException in " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Threw a Exception in " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
        }

        return dbConnection;
    }
}
```

Is there any potential problem here with my code? I am more worried about this NPE.

**StackTrace:**

```
19:14:28,372 ERROR ThreadTask:187 - Threw a SQLException in ThreadTask
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:322)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:358)
    at com.ebay.xmp.lnp.ThreadTask.getDBConnection(XMPLoadTest.java:179)
    at com.ebay.xmp.lnp.ThreadTask.run(XMPLoadTest.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:395)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
    ... 14 more
19:14:28,376 ERROR ThreadTask:139 - Threw a SQLException in ThreadTask
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ebay.xmp.lnp.ThreadTask.run(XMPLoadTest.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

Comment: Which version of oracle are you using? This java code looks fine. seems like some issue with your oracle set up. Did you tried to run this program for only 1 thread (w/o too many threads)? This link might be useful to you too http://www.dadbm.com/2011/11/oracle-listener-refused-connection-ora-12519-troubleshooting/

Comment: Thanks Prateek for the help. I forgot the Oracle version but I assumed it is `11g or 10g` Any idea about my first exception which is `Null Pointer Exception`? At what stage that can arise? In the meantime I will take a look into the article you provided me.

Comment: You haven't given exact line where this error occurs but most likely it is due to null dbConnection returned from getDBConnection method.

Comment: Please update your answer with the stack trace of the null pointer exception. One thing I could assume is the variable `dbConnection` getting set null in a race condition and another thread trying to run a `preparedStatement.executeUpdate()` on it.

Comment: I updated my question with Stacktrace as well. I also believe it is happening because of `dbConnection null` only and I am puzzled how dbConnection is null? It might be a race condition. I did debug that and figure out dbConnection was returning null. But how is that possible? And how we can fix that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The race condition is the simplest explanation because in the current code there is guarantee for the `dbConnection` to exists as non-null value when multiple threads are running.

To simply put, every `ThreadTask` object has access to the `static Connection dbConnection` class field. If for evaluation we take that there are 3 threads started during the applications initiation, and the following happens:

```
Main+----------------------------------------------------------------------(T)
    |+Thread1 --dbConnection=getDBConnection()-------------dbConnection=null|
    |                                                                       |
    |----------+Thread2 --dbConnection=getDBConnection()--------------------|dbConnection=null
    |
    |-------------+Thread3--dbConnection=getDBConnection()------------------|preparedStatement.executeUpdate()
```

At time (T), since the static variable is set to `null` by the `Thread1`, your `Thread3` will throw up the exception.

*** Update ***

You need to make use of connection pooling, check out [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/)

*** End Update ***

Comment: Thanks Vijay for making me understand this situation. So how can I fix this problem?  So that means I should be using something like this   `private Connection dbConnection = null;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;`   Right? Instead of using `static connection and statement`?

Comment: Updated my answer for clarification.

Comment: Thanks Vijay for the update. Apart from the connection pooling. There should be some other way to avoid this Race condition as well right?

Comment: Java is not my day to day work language, but I guess `ThreadLocal` should provide an option for you if you are not looking into c3p0. Check out about `ThreadLocal` at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-threads3/index.html

Comment: That update, even when it solves the problem, is not explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the very Same Scenario.

My Prerequisite Scenario :
I was working in Eclipse IDE on a Simple Hibernate program containing a insert operation.

This Exception used to occur at some inputs while INSERTION via my HIBERNATE program & did not occur at some other inputs. 
yup its sounds stupid and weird.

I was confused, I did look over answers on google n stack over flow etc.
It was a very simple observation that saved my whole Day!

If u were working in eclipse & if u encounter such same sort of scenario...
Solution :
In Eclipse, I simply Closed all the opened consoles in the 'Console' tab that got built when I executed d same program multiple times. They got stacked up & as expected it ran out of space. Closing all of them solved my problem.
This does sound like a very vague solution.
Never mind its was observation as to why that happened and the exception didn't occur again.

[The Eclipse IDE Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45n73.png)